# Why os.time{year=1970, month=1, day=1, hour=0} is not return 0 in Lua?

Tags: lua

Im in east 8+ timezone, and this expression return nil on my device.

I know it returned a value counting my timezone infomation. But, Why? I don't get it. How this function implemented and what puporse of it?
Thanks.

Comment: When I write `print(os.time{year=1970, month=1, day=1, hour=0})` on https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo it works correct for me. I'm in UTC+1 and it returns -3600

Comment: what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemention can be found here: https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/loslib.c.html#os_time

`os.time` is equivalent to [`mktime`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) in C, the result of the function is dependent on the OS lua is running on.

[On Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mktime-mktime32-mktime64?view=msvc-170#return-value), it returns -1 if the local date is before 1970-1-1 UTC. That's why you got nil. (Since Lua 5.3, it throws an error instead). If you call this function on *inx system you can get a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

I am using on Linux often Minus Epoch' for formating Dates/Timelines with `os.date()`
( My Birthday is before 1970 :-O )
Also `os.setlocale()`...

```
> os.setlocale('de_DE.UTF-8', 'time')
de_DE.UTF-8
> os.date('%c', os.time({year=1970, month=1, day=1, hour=0}))
Do 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 CET
> os.date('%c', os.time({year=1945, month=8, day=6, hour=0}))
Mo 06 Aug 1945 00:00:00 CEMT
> os.date('!%c', os.time({year=1945, month=8, day=6, hour=0}))
So 05 Aug 1945 21:00:00 GMT
> os.setlocale('ja_JP.utf8', 'time')
ja_JP.utf8
> os.date('%c', os.time({year=1945, month=8, day=6, hour=0}))
1945年08月06日 00時00分00秒
```